# Multiple Event Machine causing one to report undefined method `stop' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

I have two classes in two separate modules (I know that is not a good use for now :/)
I have something like this:

```
module MQ
  class Client

    def self.start(opts = {})
      new(opts).start
    end

    def initialize(queue, message)
      @template_message = message
      @queue = queue
    end

    def start
       EventMachine.run do
          #some code to send message via AMQP
          Signal.trap("INT")  { connection.close { EventMachine.stop { exit } }}
          Signal.trap("TERM") { connection.close {EventMachine.stop { exit(0) } }}
          Signal.trap("INFO") { puts "Current active statements: #{statements.keys.inspect}" }
        end
    end

    def stop
      EventMachine.stop
    end
  end
end
```

And next I have defined Server class:

```
module Esper
  class Server

    def self.start(opts = {})
      new(opts).start
    end

    def initialize(options)
    end

    def start
       EventMachine.run do
          #some code here to receive messages
          Signal.trap("INT")  { connection.close { EventMachine.stop { exit } }}
          Signal.trap("TERM") { connection.close {EventMachine.stop { exit(0) } }}
          Signal.trap("INFO") { puts "Current active statements: #{statements.keys.inspect}" }
        end
    end

    def stop
      EventMachine.stop
    end
  end
end
```

Now I have in rspec (and here is the error reporting):

```
context "matched messages" do

    before :each do 
      @template_message = { }

      @server = Esper::Server.new
      @client = MQ::Client.new("queue_name", @template_message)

    end

    describe "transfer" do
      it "should receive statements" do
        Thread.new do
          @server.start
        end

        Thread.new do
          @client.start
        end

        puts "Sleep for 6 seconds"
        sleep(6.0)

        #some check here

        @server.stop
        @client.stop  # and here it reports when I am trying to access nil class in class client in method stop.
      end

    end
```

It is reporting in `Client` class in method `stop` when trying to call `EventMahine.stop`
It is saying:

```
undefined method `stop' for nil:NilClass
```

Can someone point me where am I wrong and if you have any suggestion how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem because I was trying to incorporate esper and ampq.
The problem which is showing I overcome by using somewhat different approach. I still don't know why it was giving the nil pointer exception.
My solution was to use a `deamon-kit` gem for rails. I have created a deamon using this kit.

The deamon is a separate application inside my original application. That way I can test the ampq in it's separate folders and when I want to test the whole application, I can run the deamon from within original application, send data to the deamon and then check returned values in the original application.

Answer (score 0):

sooooo, this a bit tricky to explain...

you are trying to wrap code in models, which is a good thing in terms of code organization.

the thing is, it does not work that way here!

EventMachine uses a method called ReactorPattern that is very helpful if you want to handle a lot of concurrent connections simultaneously. If I am not not totally wrong, it uses a runloop to distribute work to it's clientes/reactors to handle it asynchronously. you can find a good writeup here: http://www.igvita.com/2008/05/27/ruby-eventmachine-the-speed-demon/

from what i know (which is not very much) there is just ONE runloop. i think that this is also reflected in the way you use the EventMachine API. It's all just class-methods, so global state. If you say `EventMachine.stop` once, the next call to `EventMachine.stop` will probably not work, it's already stopped. I don't know why the error is so strange though...

when you are writing a client and server application, you are usually doing this in different processes where each has it's own runloop, so that should not be a problem. it's just within your test.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just few my comments on this. The code is wrapped in Modules not Models :) I don't know whether that is the best approach, but ok.. I am trying to run Server as a Deamon. In general Server will read data from queues. In general I have used Client to be run as EventMachine, but in general it will never be run like that in the application. I have used that as a testing method that I can use in my rSpec. Hm, do you have some suggestion for that? And yes.. maybe when eventmachine is stopped then it clears all instances of it and that is why it is complaining about nil

Comment: @Aleks oh yeah, i did not models, i meant classes to be specific. i just dont think that this will work for testing. i don't know if there is any resource for how to do testing in a client server setup with both running eventmachine. i guess that the best way to do that would be to test them separately by using testdoubles for the client or the server depending on what you test.

Comment: The eventmachine for client is not necessary. I have made it only in order to test the application, but hm, maybe I could have done it some other way. Maybe in some separate thread.. to check if server is running and if so, then to send messages to the server. I don't need eventmachine mandatory to "simulate" client. Hmm.. testdoubles? In general I am looking way to test Server. The client I have made only for testing purpose.

Comment: well, than your client then is some kind of very complex test double

Comment: yes, maybe, but I don't know how can I use that information in my problem :/

Comment: I am assigning the bounty for you effort and for taking time to look and answer the question, but I will be posting my answer for this problem as I have found one way to solve this problem

Comment: You deserved it in any case ;) one answer gave me enough push to find the right solution ;) thanks